# docker-compose file doesn't raise the input my python file is asking for

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, makefile

I created a docker-compose file:

version: "3.8"

```
services:
  app:
    image: seriousgame:latest
    build: .
    environment:
      - DISPLAY=${DISPLAY}
    volumes:
      - .:/home/serious-game/
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
```

But when I run it it seems it has some issues with the the file the Dockerfile tries to start:

```
CMD ["/start.py"]
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
```

Indeed, when I run `docker-compose up`:

```
Starting serious-game_app_1 ... done
Attaching to serious-game_app_1
app_1  | Run bokeh server? ([y]/n) 
app_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
app_1  |   File "/start.py", line 24, in <module>
app_1  |     main()
app_1  |   File "/start.py", line 10, in main
app_1  |     inpt = input("Run bokeh server? ([y]/n) \n")
app_1  | EOFError: EOF when reading a line
serious-game_app_1 exited with code 1
```

So it seems it can't prompt the options my start.py file was raising. So how should I do so my docker-compose file raises the input my python file is asking for?

Comment: The best solution is probably to refactor your Python script so it doesn't require interactive input. A common approach is to allow the caller to specify the desired behavior programmatically e.g. with a command-line option. (This is not in any way specific to Docker; but running your script from Docker is certainly one use case where this design makes sense.)

Comment: Or if you have multiple main commands sharing most of the code, set the Dockerfile's `CMD` to run one of them in particular, and if you need to run another, override it with a Compose `command:`.  (Do not set `ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]`, since this will prevent you from running shell scripts or non-Python binaries; make your main scripts executable so that you don't need to manually type out the interpreter name.)